# Replacing table value based on another table value

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am new to jQuery.

I am running a fundraising campaign website that contains a list of sponsors who contributed.

The table data consists of first name (.col2), last name (.col3) and Anonymous (.col5).

It appears like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th>First name</th>
  <th>Last name</th>
  <th>Anonymous</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="col2">John</td>
  <td class="col3">Smith</td>
  <td class="col5">Y</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="col2">Jane</td>
  <td class="col3">Doe</td>
  <td class="col5">N</td>
</tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

How do I replace .col2 and .col3 with "Anonymous" if .col5 td value is "Y"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/HjpFd/2)</kbd>

```
$('td.col5').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === 'N';
}).prev().text('Anonymous').prev().text('Anonymous');
```

---

or

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/HjpFd/1)</kbd>

```
$('td.col5').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === 'N';
}).closest('tr').find('.col2,.col3').text('Anonymous');
```

or

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/HjpFd/)</kbd>

```
$('td.col5').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === 'N';
}).parent().children('.col2,.col3').text('Anonymous');
```

---

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

[.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h2jcD/)

```
$(".col5:contains('Y'), .col5:contains('y')").each(function(){
   var par = $(this).parent();
    $(par).find(".col2, .col3").text("Anonymous");
});
```

Comment: but there are a problem with contains("Y").it will work for any text with y character

Comment: .Col5 will only contain "Y" or "N" so that won't be an issue, I think. Thank you Omar!

Comment: to avoid this problem, i have modified the selector